# Replacing content using AJAX when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to use AJAX to replace the contents of a div. Although the application is fairly complex, I have tried to dumb it down in isolation so that I can get the basic concept working first.

For now, I just want to replace a div as per the PHP file...

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id = 1)
    {
        $text = 'This is some text';
    }
elseif ($id = 2) {
    {
        $text = 'This is a lot more text than the first text!';
    }
elseif ($id = 3) {
    {
        $text = 'This is a lot more text than the first text, and a load more than the third as well!!';
    }
echo $text; 
?>
```

Fairly simple stuff really. So here's my HTML file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">I want this content replacing</div>
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">ID: 1</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">ID: 2</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">ID: 3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I realise what is there will never work as I've modified some stuff I found online, but basically I'm looking to pass a variable such as the ID in the link to the AJAX script to replace the contents of the div.

How do I get this working? Is there a better alternative to using `<a>` tags?

Comment: Your PHP is not going to work. Use `===` instead of simply `=`. You're assigning the values instead of comparing them right now.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Good point! Had Missed that =)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery

Your HTML

```
<a href="#" class="ajax" data-id="1">ID: 1</a>
```

Javascript

```
// Delegate click event
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax', function(){
    
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {id: el.data('id')},
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#myDiv').html(response);
    });
    
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question using Vanilla JavaScript rather than using the **jQuery** AJAX Helper. Although it's *very* good - but learning the Vanilla way will give you a good idea of what the libraries do to aid you.

Firstly, you *are* making an Ajax call but albeit, an **Empty** one. 
    "Query" parameters is what **$_GET** is based on, are formated like:

> ?**Key**=Value&**KeyTwo**=SomeOtherValue

Which in PHP, Translates too:

```
Array
(
    [Key] => Value
    [KeyTwo] => SomeOtherValue
)
```

This'll need to be passed along with the `xmlhttp.send()` for it to make an successful ajax call, with **Data**.

But to collect this data in the first place, you must collect it with your HTML:

```
<!-- Notice how the <a> tags now have attributes attached, the id="" -->
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="loadXMLDoc( this )">ID: 1</a><br />
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="loadXMLDoc( this )">ID: 2</a>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc( Id ) {

    /**
     *  Id is the <a href="#" id="3" collected 
     *  when onclick="loadXMLDoc()" is pressed
    **/
    var xmlhttp,
        DataId = Id.attributes.id.value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else 
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;   
    }

    /**
     *  Notice the ?id="+ dataId +"
     *  It's passing through the ID Collected
    **/
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?id="+ dataId +"",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Although this code above is very inefficient, you would be much better in JavaScript & Programming in general to keep things generic. By modifying your code to:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="idlistener">ID: 1</a><br />
<a href="#" id="2" class="idlistener">ID: 2</a>

<script>
    function getId() {
        alert( this.attributes.id.value );
        //Click on id="2", alerts '2'
    }

    /**
     *  We find all the HTML tags with the
     *  attribute that has 'class="idlistener"
     *  attached, we 'bind' it to a function called
     *      getId()
    **/
    var IdListener = document.getElementsByClassName('idlistener');
    for( var x = 0; x < IdListener.length; x++ ) {
         IdListener[x].addEventListener( 'click', getId, false );
    }
</script>
```

**Demo**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvHcc/3/)

Lastly, It does look to me you've discovered this AJAX Code from W3Schools.com. I think you'll find every StackOverflow Web Developer that would agree with me - **Don't** learn from this Site!

Answer (score 0):

General format for replacing html content with the response from an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: yourUrl,
  method: 'get', // or 'post'
  success: function (response) {
      $('#myDiv').html(response);
  }
  // other ajax options here if you need them
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use ajax for that. Just use the following in the condition. Dont forget to call the jquery js file on the header. Otherwise jquery wont work:

```
echo '<script>$("#myDiv").html("This is some text")</script>';
```